# Word 2010 - Field code to reference 2nd level of outline number only

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, outline

I'm working on a template document in Word 2010 that will serve as a Chapter (outline level 1, heading 1 format) in a larger Volume. In the Chapter, I need to have multiple Sections (outline level 2, heading 2 format). I want to use field codes to get the section number without the chapter number for use throughout the Section.

For example:

```
Chapter 20 - Chapter Title
20.1 Section One Title
20.1.1 Section One Subsection
  Something here needs a label that reads only '1', in reference to the 20.1 2nd number.
20.2 Section Two Title
  Something here needs a label that reads only '2', in reference to the 20.2 2nd number.
...
```

I am able to get "20.1" and "20.2" via STYLREF like `{ STYLEREF 2 \s }`.

How can I get just "1" and "2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help feeling that there must be an easier way, but if your numbers only range from 1 to 9 (e.g. 14.1-14.9, 20.1-20.9 etc., you could try the following nested fields (All the {} need to be the special "field code brace" characters you can enter with ctrl-F9, not the ordinary ones you type on the keyboard).

> { =10*{ STYLEREF 2 \s #.x } }

If you need 2 digits, things get more complicated, e.g.

> { ={ QUOTE "{ STYLEREF 2 \s }1" #.xxx }*{ IF "{ QUOTE "{ STYLEREF 2 \s }1" #.xxx }" = ".???" 100 10 } #0 }

Comment: It seems like it should be easier, but this is as ugly as I feared it would be. I did have to add a \ to all of the #s in the field codes to solve some syntax errors (changed to `\#`), but it works! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the backslashes-keep forgetting they need special treatment here